# Eclipse JavaScript Fold Function Ability Disappeared Even With Folding Enabled

Tags: javascript, eclipse

For a while now I could collapse and expand functions without any problems in my JavaScript files. Suddenly all of the +/- buttons next to the line numbers disappeared for all functions. Folding for JavaScript is enabled and it is clear there is space next to the line numbers for the buttons.

I'm using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had just created a new function and I had included in the function parameters the `var` declaration:

```
// No functions could be folded
function foobar(var foo, var bar) {
...
}
```

Removing the `var` for each parameter solved the folding problems:

```
// All functions can now be folded again
function foobar(foo, bar) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as an information, the shortcuts for expand or collapse in Eclipse are the following :

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>: activate collapsing (- or + appear next to the functions)
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>MAJ</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>: collapse all functions
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd>: expand all functions

Comment: In my situation I tried using those commands and they would not work because of the `var` declaration in the function header.